# How to build with boost-build on Travis-CI?

Tags: ubuntu, boost, travis-ci, boost-build

I am trying to build my project in the excellent Travis-CI (which I use for other projects where the build system is GNU make).

My project builds with [boost-build](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/) and I am trying to find the right apt-get package to use, but the simple `boost-build` didn't work. Does anyone know if there is a package for `boost-build`? Also it would be very helpful if someone knew how to look for a package name that would be available via the travis-ci. I believe they run Ubuntu, which I'm not familiar with (I use Arch).

Here is my *.travis.yml* (if it helps)

```
language: cpp
compiler: gcc 
before_script:
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
  - sudo apt-get -qq update
  - sudo apt-get -qq install g++-4.8 valgrind boost-build
  - export CXX="g++-4.8"
  - git submodule update --init --recursive
script:
  - b2
```

The error is very simple:

```
$ sudo apt-get -qq install g++-4.8 valgrind boost-build
E: Package 'boost-build' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Yes, Travis uses Ubuntu. I didn't see any recent packages for it but it does look like you can download it from the website and install it quite easily.

Comment: Yeah, I have it working now by downloading sources from github and building it in the Travis VM. But that's far from ideal since this is a build tool and should be available on the system. I see that a package is available in Ubuntu Lucid though. Is it possible to install packages from Lucid on 12.04?

Comment: I don't think so, though there may be hacks. Plus, lucid came out in 2008, so the package problaby wouldn't work anyway with newer versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this on your .travis.yml

```
before_install:
    # or another boost version
    - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apokluda/boost1.53 --yes
    - sudo apt-get update

install:
    # or another boost version
    - sudo apt-get install libboost-system1.53-dev
    - sudo apt-get install libboost-regex1.53-dev
    - sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem1.53-dev
```

Comment: thanks! but boost 1.53 is not sufficient for me. I'm using 1.56. What I ended up doing was build my own boost-build ubuntu package and hosting it in my server and downloading it in travis.